# socket.io | losing messages due to frequency and volume

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have around 5700 messages (each message is a 100x100 image as a Base64 string) which I emit from the server to the client from within a for-loop, pretty fast:

```
[a pretty big array].forEach((imgAsBase64) => {
  io.emit('newImgFromServer', imgAsBase64)
})
```

The client only receives from 1700 to 3000 of them in total, before I get a:

```
disconnected due to =  transport error
socket connected
```

Once the socket re-connects (and the for-loop has not ended) the emission of new messages from within the loop resumes but I have lost those previous ones forever.

How can I make sure that the client receives all of the messages every time ?

Comment: Do you mean your code is causing event loop blockage, triggering the disconnect? Or do you mean a general solution to apply in face of network issues?

Comment: I don't know what the cause is. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening. Right now I'm only hypothesising that it is due to the frequency of the messages and their volume. Each message is a 100x100 image as a Base64 string.

Comment: Does it take about 45 seconds? If so, you are probably hitting https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#pingtimeout

Comment: But why would the connection timeout if there is constant activity from the server to the client as it is in my case? If there was no activity for more than 45secs it would makes sense, but here it's the exact opposite: there is constant activity.

Comment: You're right - most protocols would treat activity as a sign of healthiness. Not socket.io - it actually needs to get a ping back! The same has happened to me in the past with some big JSON data.

Comment: You were right, it was the pingTimeout. I increased it and now it works. But there was a  lot of blockage  anyway so I'm now wrapping every `emit` in a `setTimeout` and everything is a lot smoother. Thanks!

Comment: Might be best to package 100 of these into one message rather than sending so many smaller messages.  You will still have to make sure you don't starve the responses by giving a short pause after sending a few messages, but sending a LOT fewer messages with larger payloads would likely be better in nearly all respects.

Comment: Thanks I will try that as well. Make sure you turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is an interesting example of **"starving the event loop"**.  If you're in a tight `for` loop for some period of time with no `await` in the loop, then you don't let the event loop process any other events during the duration of the `for` loop.  If some events need to be processed during that time for things to work properly, you get problems. Read on for how that applies to this case.

Both client and server need some occasional cycles to process housekeeping pings and pongs in the socket.io protocol.  If you firehose messages from one end to the other in a non-stop `for` loop, you can starve the ability to process those housekeeping messages and it will think that it has timed out (not received the housekeeping messages when it should have which is usually a sign of a lost or inoperative connection).  In reality, the housekeeping messages are sitting in the event loop waiting to be processed, but if you never give the event loop a chance to process them, some other code running in the `for` loop will think that they never arrived.

So, you have to make sure you give both ends enough occasional cycles to process those housekeeping messages.  The typical way to do that is to just make sure that you aren't fire hosing messages.  Send N messages, then pause for a short period of time (enough time for the event loop to be able to service any incoming network events).  Then send N more, pause, etc...

In addition, you could make this whole process a lot more efficient by combining a number of the Base64 strings into a single message.  You can probably just put them into an array of 100 of them and send that array of 100 and repeat until they are all sent.  Then, obviously change the client to expect an array of Base64 strings instead of just a single one.  This will obviously result in a lot fewer messages to send (which is more efficient), but you will still need to pause every so often to let the server process things in the event loop.

Exactly how many messages to send before pausing is something that could be figured out via trial and error, but if you put 100 images into a single message and send 10 of these larger messages (which sends 1,000 images) and then pause for even just 50ms, that should be enough time for the event loop to service any inbound ack messages from socket.io to avoid the timeout.  Any sort of pause using `setTimeout()` makes the `setTimeout()` get in line behind most other messages that are waiting in the event loop so even a short pause with `setTimeout()` tends to accomplish the goal of letting the event loop process the things that were waiting to be run.

If end-to-end time was super important, you could experiment with sending more messages at once and/or changing the pause time, but you don't want to end with a setting that is close to where you get a timeout (you want some safety factor).